# Attach movement to each list object

Tags: unity, movement, spawning

How would i move every sphere that gets spawned every 2 seconds ? Basically i want every sphere to follow the previous spawned sphere or even all N-1 spheres should follow the first spawned sphere along a predefined path and they should keep rolling as a train of spheres. I am lost when i try to imprint movement to each sphere.

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] prefabs;
    public List<GameObject> listBalls = new List<GameObject>();
    private GameObject x;
    public int timer = 0;
    private float movementSpeed = 5f;

    void Start()
    {
        createBall();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time - timer > 0.8f)
        {
            createBall();
            timer += 2;
        }
        listBalls[listBalls.Count-1].transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void createBall()
    {
        x = prefabs[Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length)];
        Instantiate(x, x.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        listBalls.Add(x);
    }

    void moveBall(GameObject x, GameObject y)
    {
        x.transform.position += y.transform.position - new Vector3(0,0,-1);
    }
}

Loop added but movement staggered

        void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time - timer > 0.8f)
        {
            createBall();
            timer += 2;
        }
        foreach (GameObject item in listBalls)
        {
            item.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

```
````

Comment: Are you familiar with using loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, depending on how exactly you want the balls to move. Most solutions are going to use some kind of *loop*. If you aren't familiar with loops, you should read some tutorials on loops in C#.

**Example 1: All balls move same direction/distance each frame**

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(0, 0, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

foreach (var ball in listBalls) {
    ball.transform.position += movement;
}
```

**Example 2: Each ball moves towards the next ball**

```
float distance = movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
//move the last ball
listBalls[listBalls.Count - 1].transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, distance);

//move each ball (except the last) towards the next ball
for (int i = 0; i < listBalls.Count - 1; i++) { //note we don't want to move the last ball again
    Transform ball = listBalls[i].transform;
    Transform nextBall = listBalls[i + 1].transform;
    ball.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(ball.position, nextBall.position, distance);
}
```

Comment: i litterally just did that, edit added, but the movement is staggered, i suspect the foreach loop shouldnt be added in the Update method? I am looking for a Zuma like movement of the balls.

Comment: @mavish What do you mean by "the movement is stagged"? You'll need to run the loop regularly to update the positions of all of the balls; `Update()` is generally a good starting place for that kind of thing.